# Update different table records with same parameters in spring data jpa efficiently

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation where I have 8 tables with some common parameters like Firstname ,Lastname and Price.

Now I am reading an excel file with these 3 above details.
Now the condition is if a price in the excel matches the price in 10 different tables then i have to update the records of those tables with firstname and lastname from the excel file respectively.

So what Am doing is fetching the all 8 records one by one and then running a loop for each table entity in java and comparing the price and updating the fname and lname . Below is the code -->

```
    List<Person> findAll = personRepository.findAll();
    for (Person p : findAll) {
        if (p.getPrice().equalsIgnoreCase(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
            p.setFname(row1.getCell(fname).getNumericCellValue());
            p.setLname(row1.getCell(lname).getNumericCellValue()));
            personRepository.save(p);
        }
    }
    List<Address> findAllb = addRepository.findAll();
    for (Address add : findAllb ) {
        if (add.getPrice().equalsIgnoreCase(cell.getStringCellValue())) {
            add.setFname(row1.getCell(fname).getNumericCellValue());
            add.setLname(row1.getCell(lname).getNumericCellValue());
            addRepository.save(add);
        }
    }
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Similarly I have more different tables. In this way Select statement are running 8 times as well as update statements.

**Is there any way to do it efficiently? without hitting the db 16 times (8 for select , 8 for updates)  .The DB is POSTGRES**

Comment: If they contain the same kind of data, why are there 10 tables in the first place?

Comment: Its not same data, I am talking about same column , data can be anything.